# Meaning of "makeshift dias"?

Tags: meaning, subcontinental-english

What is the meaning of *makeshift dias* in this passage?

> He had invited over a hundred guests, including members of the press. He addressed everyone from a *makeshift dias*.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. What is a dias? What does makeshift mean? Please tell us what definitions you found in a dictionary, and why this remains confusing to you. Also, please take our tour to find out what kinds of questions are a good fit for this site; you might also want to that the tour at our sister site, [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: As noted in an answer below _dias_ should be spelled _dais_. This might add further difficulties in understanding because I believe _dai/dais_ is an Indian term for midwife.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is based on a typographical error.

Answer (score 4):

The correct spelling is "dais".

According to Wikipedia:

> A dais is any raised platform located either inside or outside of a room or enclosure, often for dignified occupancy, as at the front of a lecture hall or  sanctuary.

*Makeshift* means *cobbled together out of whatever is available*. For example, you can make a table out of an upturned bucket with a flat piece of wood on top.

Comment: Makeshift means "cobbled together out of whatever is available". For example, you can make a table out of an upturned bucket with a flat piece of wood on top...